# I have a date string with the format '12/Sep/21'. I want to change the format to '2021-09-12'. How can I do this in Python?

Tags: python, date

I have a date string with the format `'12/Sep/21'`. I want to change the format to `'2021-09-12'`. How can I do this in Python?

I tried this:

```
dte1 = '02/Sep/21'
dte2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(dte1, '%d %b %y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
dte2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may mean by:

```
import datetime
dte1 = '02/Sep/21'
dte2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(dte1, '%d/%b/%y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(dte2)
```

Output:

```
2021-09-02
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s so easy to convert a date format into your desired date format by using the *datetime* package of Python:

```
import datetime
your_date = '02/Sep/21'
desire_format = datetime.datetime.strptime(your_date, '%d/%b/%y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(desire_format)
```

#### Output

```
2021-09-02
```